# Update virtualized ubuntu server 14.04.6 to 16.04 - error No new release found

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, apt, server, updates

I am trying to update a virtualized Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS by ssh (Putty).

I have tried multiple methods and they all indicate "No new release found"

Ubuntio information is
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

*method 1*

```
# sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
# sudo apt-get install -y update-manager screen
# sudo screen
# sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Ubuntu is not updated - No new release found

*method 2*

```
# sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
# do-release-upgrade -d
# sudo apt-get update
```

Ubuntu is not updated - No new release found

Is there any other method to update or it is no longer possible to update Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS to 16.04

Comment: Officially it is not possible. There is a hacky way to replace repos in `sources.list`, but that may work, or not. Why not do a new install?

Comment: Both those methods have mistakes in them, so it's not surprising that neither work. Please don't copy-and-paste magic shell incantations into your system; those usually just break your system. Backup your data and clean-install a newer (supported) release of Ubuntu. It takes approximately the same amount of time as an upgrade, and much less can go wrong. Be sure to mark your calendar so you remember to upgrade on time.

Comment: Luigi, upgrades from 14.04 to 16.04 _are_ supported here, and _are_ possible. 1) Are you in a situation where you _have_ to do this by ssh because you don't have immediate access to the machine you are upgrading? 2) Is it practical to do a complete reinstall and then restore your configuration and data from backup? If not, why must you do an upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 without a reinstall? This helps us understand your situation.

Comment: @K7AAY -- The server is virtualized and has the console version of Ubuntu Server, access to it is by ssh (Putty), but I can migrate the applications to a new server and install Ubuntu 16.04, I think it would be the best option

Comment: Why `do-release-upgrade -d`?; the -d means go to development release (ie. 20.04) which is **not** possible from 14.04. The fact that you didn't get the development release error message implies to me you system is fully upgraded (14.04 has been EOL for awhile, mirrors can drop archives post-EOL so you should read your `apt-get update` output for any issues due to this far past EOL date).

Comment: @guiverc Hi, thanks for your help. I read that the `do-release-upgrade -d` instruction was to force the installation. It is already clear to us, -d is development.. I managed to update with `do-release-upgrade -p`. I think the `-p` _would be production ?_.. _source Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (console) update to 16.04, 18.04 LTS server console._ `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove` `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core` `sudo cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` _validate or edit Prompt = lts_  `sudo do-release-upgrade -p`

Comment: '-d' forces a latest release (19.10) to the development release (20.04) and will do nothing with prior releases (other than messages saying you'll need to move to latest/19.10 first). '-p' is proposed; refer `man do-release-upgrade` to see the reference manual page for your actual release.14.04 can go to 16.04, then you'll need to reboot to fully be in 16.04.  A 16.04 can then bump to 18.04

Answer (score 0):

If you present this failure when updating, the correct way to **update the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to the server console 16.04 LTS.**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

we edit the line `Prompt =` and replace `Prompt = lts`

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -p
```

We validate the version and specified the repositories

```
hostnamectl
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install
```

*if you present this error*

*apt-get: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: symbol _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7compareERKS4_, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference*

We download and install the packages (libstdc ++ 6 and gcc-5-base) corresponding to our system
https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/libstdc++6/download

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/amd64/libstdc++6/download

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/gcc-5-base/download

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/gcc-5-base/download

we copy to the server using the WinSCP program, install the packages

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

finished the installation we execute the commands

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
```

**Update Ubuntu server 16.04.6 LTS to 18.04 LTS (console)**

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade -p
sudo apt-get update
```

Ready OS updated